# Find EId and EName

Tags: sql, database

Here is the schema -

```
CREATE TABLE EMp(eId integer PRIMARY KEY, Name nvarchar(max), age integer);

CREATE TABLE Project(pId integer PRIMARY KEY, pName nvarchar(max), ploc nvarchar(max));

CREATE TABLE EmpProject(eid integer, FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES EMp(eid), pid integer FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Project(pId), hrs integer);
```

I need to find the name and ID of the employee who works on atleast 3 projects but none in 'Mumbai'

I have tried many options the last one being -

```
select eid, Name from EMp E, Project P, EmpProject EP where  
EP.pNum = P.pId and P.ploc <> 'Mumbai' 
and E.eId in (select eno from EmpProject group by eno having count(*) >=3 )
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, group by employee and set the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
select E.eid, E.Name 
from EMp E 
inner join EmpProject EP on EP.eid = E.eid
inner join Project P  on P.pid = EP.pid
group by E.eid, E.Name
having count(distinct P.pid) >= 3 and sum(case when P.ploc = 'Mumbai' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: The query is showing syntax error near the 'Mumbai').
Expecting AND/OR/','

Comment: Can you please modify this solution to use inner queries as to its a restriction in exam

I am using

-------------------------------------------->>>>>
select E.eid, E.Name from EMp E where E.eId in 
(select distinct EP.eno from EmpProject EP where EP.pNum in
(select P.pId from Project P where P.ploc <>'Mumbai') group by EP.eno having count(*)>=3)-------------------------->>>>>>

Comment: What is `eno` and `pNum`? I can't find these columns in any of th e3 tables.

Comment: select E.eid, E.Name from EMp E where E.eId in (select distinct EP.eid from EmpProject EP where EP.pId in (select P.pId from Project P where P.ploc <>'Mumbai') group by EP.eId having count(*)>=3)

Please find the corrected column name

Comment: It's for my exam tomorrow can you please help with a solution?

Comment: `where EP.pId in (select P.pId from Project P where P.ploc <>'Mumbai')` is wrong. It will not give correct results. So if you want to keep `IN` you will have to something like: `select eid, Name 
from EMp 
where eId in (
  select distinct EP.eid 
  from EmpProject EP inner join Project P
  on P.pid = EP.pid
  group by EP.eId 
  having count(*) >= 3 and sum(case when P.ploc = 'Mumbai' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
)`

Comment: Can we do this without Joins?

Comment: Please let me know if it can be done or not without joins @forpas

Comment: I can't find a way without joining at least 2 of the tables. If it could be done it would be too complex.